# Do XY coordinates refer to a shapefile, whereas Lat Long refers to the globe

Tags: latitude-longitude, xy

I have data from [City of New York](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/DSNY-Graffiti-Information/gpwd-npar)

Instead of file showing Latitude Longitude it shows XY coordinate.

Please clarify, does XY coordinate refer to shapefile (which was not included), whereas Latitude Longitude references points on a globe?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your data

Comment: The x and y ordinates in that dataset are referring to the location of the point, as you would expect latitude and longitude to. However in this case, the dataset uses a difference coordinate system. It's not clear to me (I'm from the U.K.) which coordinate reference system the data is using but my guess would be some version of nad83

Comment: What is in the prj file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your provided data, reading up the [technical standards for spatial data of NYC](https://gis.ny.gov/coordinationprogram/workgroups/wg_1/related/standards/datum.htm) and browsing through applicable gcs in QGIS, i was able to find something. Checked it with OSM-Map in QGIS. The red dots are your data aka graffito-locations and their conditions in NYC.

[image: NYC Graffio-Locations]
NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet

**ESRi WKID:102718 aka EPSG:2263**

- Try adding the CSV as textlayer. Separator is comma ' , '
- Define x-coordinate as x and y-coordinate as y ;)
- Uncheck gms-coords (red circle)
- After confirmation define the GCS with EPSG: 2263
  [image: QGIS 'Add text as layer'-window]

AND finally answering your question: The provided x/y-coords-pairs are representing points in a projected coordinate system (here WKID:102718 EPSG: 2263) with cartesian axes.

P.S.: Please note that i'm not from the US, so any additonal insight on nyc gcs is welcome.

Comment: Very thorough answer!

Comment: Actual EPSG wkid is 2263. 102718 is an older Esri wkid for the same CRS.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for your insight! Funny thing QGIS is holding the ESRI WKID (proprietary) as EPSG (ESRI WKID ≠ EPSG)

Comment: Out of date, probably! It's hard to keep track of the wkid changes.