# Address Listed on Open Data but cannot geo-locate

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, address

I am researching [graffiti incidents in New York City](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/DSNY-Graffiti-Information/gpwd-npar).

One of the addresses entered is `Frederick Avenue And West 179Th Street,Bronx,New York`

Cannot geocode, i.e. find the latitude and longitude of this

I tried googling this, but even google maps cannot find.

How do I deduce where this can be.

For instance, there is an address entry, `South East Corner Of Amsterdam Avenue And Cross Bronx Expressway,Manhattan,New York`, and I can approximate it to the exit of Cross Bronx Expressway that takes one to Amsterdam Avenue, i.e. [Exit 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Bronx_Expressway#Exit_list).

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: you will never get 100% match... someone can make a mistake when giving/writing/reading the address, the street name might have changed (but still commonly used locally) etc.

Comment: There are 10628 records with X_COORDINATE and Y_COORDINATE you will have to either remove the remaining or use a manual check of the rest of the records but with Address as 49 49 your have a hard time matching those remaining addresses. These X,Y coords need reprojecting into lat/lng, do you know the local NYC UTM projection?

Comment: @Mapperz See I know nothing about projections, but someone answered another question of mine, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243416/do-xy-coordinates-refer-to-a-shapefile-whereas-lat-long-refers-to-the-globe I believe it is EPSG: 102718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching in QGIS globule search plugin using the trial " West 179Th Street,Bronx,New York".
It find me this address [image]
I was using the "WGS 84" CRS and the coordinate are -73.91492,40.85570

Comment: If this was helpful please mark this as "answer". Thanks